# Fundamental group of two spheres in a cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-homomorphism

Hi I'm a little bit stuck on this problem

> Let $$S_1 =\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1\}\\S_2 =\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+(y+1)^2+z^2=1\}$$
> consider also
> $$C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2 = 4, z\in [-2,2]\}$$
> and union of upper and lower cylinder's basis $$B =\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2 \leq 4, z =-2,z= 2\}$$ Calculate the fundamental group $\pi_1(S_1\cup S_2\cup B\cup C, p)$ where $P=(0,2,0)$

I represent everything on the cartesian plane and it's a cylinder of radius $2$ and two radius $1$ spheres touching in the origin and tangent to $C$. I've tried SVK theorem but I could not say anything useful, even though I have a feeling that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Here's why I think that (sorry for the poor drawing)
[image: possible loop on the space]

I think that every loop that goes only on the cylinder like $\alpha$ are homotopic to the constant loop, the same holds for all the loops that goes on the spheres and come back to $P$ whitout going on the cylinder. So I think the only loop that is important is $\delta$ the yellow one going on the spheres and cylinder. I honestly don't know if what I'm saying make sense and I still don't know how to calculate this fundamental group. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the cylinder include the discs on the top and bottom? From the parametric equations you've given, I don't think it does. Therefore, I don't think a loop like $\alpha$ is possible (although it may just be me failing to interpret the drawing properly), and I don't think the answer to whether or not any loops only on the cylinder are necessarily null-homotopic is immediate.

Comment: @legionwhale thank you, I will edit the post the cylinder includes also the two basis. Btw do you think (cylinder basis included) is not so simple to conclude that the loop is null-homotopic?

Comment: If the discs are included, then yes, I agree that loops like $\alpha$ are null-homotopic. I also agree that it seems plausible in that case that the group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @legionwhale Ok and if we substitute the cylinder with a sphere or a square is irrelevant (homotopically speaking)? I don't know If I'm explaining myself clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$ is correct. Here is a way to see that your space is homotopy equivalent to a wedge product of a circle and three spheres, which shows the fundamental group is $\pi_1(S^1)*\pi_1(S^2)*\pi_1(S^2)*\pi_1(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}*1*1*1=\mathbb{Z}$:

[image: homotopy equivalence]

I hope it is clear that the last space is indeed equivalent to a wedge product of a circle and three spheres.

Comment: So I should remember that every time I have shapes attached I can substitute the attachment point with a contractible space, like a segment in this case. In conclusion the fundamental group of the wedge product is $\mathbb{Z}$ because spheres are tre trivial group and remains the circle, right?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt $1 \to 2$ makes use of the fact that spaces are homotopy equivalent if they are strong deformation retracts of the same space. Therefore, as you observe, replacing a point with a contractible space has no effect modulo homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks, and what about my last comment above do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt I believe that's correct. The proof I saw that, for instance, the wedge product of $n$ circles has fundamental group the free group on $n$ letters was nothing other than handwaving, so I'm not sure if there is a more rigorous proof, but your reasoning should be sufficient for most purposes, at least.